# How do I configure the keyboard and mouse in BlueStacks?

Tags: bluestacks, keyboard-shortcuts

What's the best way to edit the keymap and mouse controls for BlueStacks in any particular android application?

For example, right now I've recently picked up Future Fight and I'd like to bind 1 and 2 to the special attacks that I currently have to click with the mouse on icons in the lower right-hand corner.

You can currently in BlueStacks .9 hit Control+Alt+I to open a Keyboard Input Mapper Tool.  The sample file it generates for the current application has examples of how to bind keys to virtually tilting the device in various directions, but I'd really like to bind particular mouse clicks to the keyboard.

And of course (in many other games) find a way to bind the mouse roller to zoom in and out.

Comment: Here's related answer of mine on [how to configure bluestacks for mapping control to the keyboard?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/109436/27149).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest (mid May 2015) update of Bluestacks adds a graphical interface for editing keystrokes for the current application.  It's a HUGE improvement for those who don't have the aptitude or time for programming.

Answer (score -1):

You can do so currently in BlueStacks .9. Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open "Keyboard Input Mapper Tool".  The sample file it generates for the current application has examples of how to bind keys to virtually tilt the device in various directions.

Comment: I see the duplicate content taken from the question. Is this supposed to be the correct answer? If so, then please remove "the answer" on the question. If not, then could you explain why did you post this as an answer?